# MAMP "localhost" doesn't work unlike 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, localhost, mamp

What to do to fix this?
my etc/hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

and using terminal with command:

```
file -b /etc/hosts
```

i got

```
ASCII English text, with CR line terminators
```

but "localhost" still doesn't work. What should i do more?

Comment: Are you using ipv6 ?

Comment: How to check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You saved the file with incorrect line-endings (carriage return instead of newline characters) therefore it looks like one line to unix. You need to save /etc files with newline line endings (unix)
To do so you could use a good plaintext editor like TextWrangler.
Alternatively you could use this command in Terminal:

```
sudo perl -pi -e's/\015/\012/g' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: how to save file with newline characters? I use Sublime Text. File -> save with encoding?

Comment: sudo perl -pi -e's/\015/\012/g' /etc/hosts

Comment: It worked:-) thank You. Would You explain me what does every part of this expression?

Comment: As root perl does an inline stream-edit to replace ascii code 15 with ascii code 10.

Comment: Would be good to edit your answer and add the code to it.